# Access Textboxes Adding Values

Tags: vba, ms-access, math, textbox, subroutine

I have an access database, with a form, that contains numerous textboxes. The textboxes are filled with currency data based on a selection made by the user. Each record may have different values some may have no values. I need to add 3 of the txtboxes together but the value always shows as Null.

```
me.txt1 = Nz(me.txt2.value + me.txt3.value + me.txt3.value)
txt2 = 23.04
txt3 = Null(empty)
txt4 = 15.64
```

The value of txt1 should be 38.68 instead its coming out Null. The textboxes are populated by a subroutine that is called from the AfterUpdate event of a dropdown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where do you use that formula ? Is it in VBA ? You don't need it.
If it's from the Control Source of txt1, then `Me`should be replaced by `Form` (or by nothing at all)

In the Control Source property of txt1, type `= nz(txt2)+nz(txt3)+nz(txt4)`
That should be all you need. No VBA.
Another solution, IF the source of the form is a Query, is to add a calculated field in the query.
In both cases, of course you will NOT store that data (which would violate 3rd Normal form)

Comment: This works!! Typing it into Control source worked first time Thanks!!